# Add Genegic interface into service. How does this code work?

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm trying to implement Repository and Unit Of Work in my Dotnet core project.

I have a line code like this:

```
 services.AddScoped(typeof(IEfRepository<>), typeof(EfRepository<>));
```

```
public interface IEfRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// SingleOrDefault expression
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="predicate"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        Task<TEntity> SingleOrDefaultAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
...
```

And implement:

```
 public class EfRepository<TEntity> : IEfRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Fields
        /// </summary>
        private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
        private DbSet<TEntity> _entities;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new instance of the <see cref=" EfRepository{TEntity}"/> class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dbContext"></param>
        public EfRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }
```

When request is sent from mediator. It is handled in Handler class and service is injected from contructor:

```
public class KiemtracongtrinhQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetKiemtracongtrinhQuery, GKiemtracongtrinhDto>,
                                                IRequestHandler<ListKiemtracongtrinhQuery, IEnumerable<GKiemtracongtrinhDto>>
    {

        private readonly IGKiemtracongtrinhRepository _gKiemtracongtrinhRepository;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new instance of the <see cref="KiemtracongtrinhQueryHandler"/> class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gKiemtracongtrinhRepository"></param>
        /// <param name="mapper"></param>
        public KiemtracongtrinhQueryHandler(IGKiemtracongtrinhRepository gKiemtracongtrinhRepository,
                                            IMapper mapper)
        {
            _gKiemtracongtrinhRepository = gKiemtracongtrinhRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(gKiemtracongtrinhRepository));
            _mapper = mapper ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapper));
        }
```

Comment: Can you show service class and how repository is used there?

Comment: I have just updated my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right way. Some fixes would be:

1. In the EfRepository class.

```
 public class EfRepository<TEntity> : IEfRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Fields
        /// </summary>
        private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new instance of the <see cref=" EfRepository{TEntity}"/> class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dbContext"></param>
        public EfRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new instance of the <see cref=" EfRepository{TEntity}"/> class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dbContext"></param>
        public EfRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }
        ///Example method
        public async Task AddItem(T item)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Add(item);
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        ///Example method
        public async Task<List<T>> GetAllRecords(T exampleItem)
        {
            return _context.Set<T>().ToList();
        }
```

I can not see the reason DbEtities should be here.

2) Your handler:

```
public class KiemtracongtrinhQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetKiemtracongtrinhQuery, GKiemtracongtrinhDto>,
                                                IRequestHandler<ListKiemtracongtrinhQuery, IEnumerable<GKiemtracongtrinhDto>>
    {

        private readonly IEfRepository<GKiemtracongtrinhRepository> _gKiemtracongtrinhRepository;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new instance of the <see cref="KiemtracongtrinhQueryHandler"/> class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gKiemtracongtrinhRepository"></param>
        /// <param name="mapper"></param>
        public KiemtracongtrinhQueryHandler(IEfRepository<GKiemtracongtrinhRepository> gKiemtracongtrinhRepository,
                                            IMapper mapper)
        {
            _gKiemtracongtrinhRepository = gKiemtracongtrinhRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(gKiemtracongtrinhRepository));
            _mapper = mapper ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapper));
        }
```

In the handler you need to pass the generic repository.

If you want you can take a look at this example: https://github.com/steliosgiakoumidis/NotificationDatabase

Regarding the UnitOfWork, the way you can use it is the following:

```
    public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        IRepository2 Repository1{ get; }
        IRepository2 Repository2 { get; }
        IRepository3 Repository3 { get; }

        Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        public IRepository1 Repository1 { get; }
        public IRepository2 Repository2 { get; }
        public IRepository3 Repository3 { get; }

        private readonly _dbContext;

        public UnitOfWork(IRepository1  repository1, IRepository2 repository2,
            IRepository3 repository3)
        {
            Repository1 = repository1;
            Repository2 = repository2;
            Repository3 = repository3;
        }

        public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error($"An error occured when saving changes to the database.)
            }
        }
}
```

It is a good practice to pass the SaveChanges in the UnitOfWork and execute the method after all database actions are complete. SaveChanges method is usually called not in the database/infrastructure layer of the application layer instead. 
Using the unit of work you can save quite a lot of injections. Since you bundle all your repositories into one UoW and you inject this instead.

Myself I have not used generic repostiries and UoW, but I prefered to use an abstract class instead, but the main idea is the same.

Comment: I have alot of Repo, How can I declare repository in UnitofWork class like this:  public IRepository1 Repository1 { get; }

Comment: Exactly as you saw in the example above. You have to be careful when you in your startup class when you register services, all the individual repositories should be registered first.

services.AddScoped<IRepository1, Repository1>()
services.AddScoped<IRepository2, Repository2>()
.....
services.AddScoped<IUnitofWork, UnitofWork>()